Cmake target_compile_options with PRIVATE sets compile options for linked libraries as well
Im using target_compile_options to set compiler options for the executable file:
target_compile_options( main_full PRIVATE
        ### Gnu/Clang C Options
        $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:C,GNU>:-fdiagnostics-color=always>
        $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:C,Clang>:-fcolor-diagnostics>

        $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:C,Clang,GNU>:-Wall>
        $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:C,Clang,GNU>:-Wextra>
        $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:C,Clang,GNU>:-Werror>
        $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:C,Clang>:-Weverything>
        )

This causes the compiler options to be set to the other libraries that are linked to the executable (-Werror).
This is how the executable is linked:
target_link_libraries(
        main_full
        pico_stdlib
        FreeRTOS-Kernel
        FreeRTOS-Kernel-Heap4
        pico_cyw43_arch_none
)

If I remove the compiler option (-Werror) that causes the issue from the target_compile_options the project builds fine.
Am I missing something? Is there some other settings that can cause this?

Are you sure that your dependent libraries (pico_stdlib, etc) have PRIVATE sources and not PUBLIC or INTERFACE?

"This causes the compiler options to be set to the other libraries that are linked to the executable" - No, this is definitely not the case. Please, show more code (in form of [mcve]) and the complete error message: it includes the source file, which are compiled, and the object file, which is produced.

@PavelTsayukov the dependent libraries are built source files as either PUBLIC or INTERFACE

@PavelTsayukov target_sources(pico_cyw43_driver INTERFACE             cyw43_driver.c) this is how the file with the error is included in the library.

@tonyjosi look at INTERFACE_SOURCES. When you put sources of the library in INTERFACE scope, these sources will populate that target property. And a consuming target that links against the library (e.g. pico_cyw43_driver) will be compiled with these sources and compile options of the consuming target will be applied to these sources as well.
